# Blender to Unity - How to Maintain ChildOf Constraint without Breaking other Clips

Tags: animation, export, workflow, unity

Working on an FPS Game (Using Unity 2019.3 & Blender 2.8) and starting to try more techniques with my animations in blender in terms of reloads, movement, etc. I have the system coded (I'm primarily a programmer) so I wanted to push the art side a bit and begin animating well.

With my FPS blend file, (Saving Directly as a Blend File To Unity) I have two arms that are rigged with Inverse Kinematics, and work just fine, I then have a rifle with a base bone controlling the general shape (weight painted - No Slide) and I have a bone controlling the magazine that is a "childof" the base bone using the constraint. This is a separate armature, with the base bone being a child on the hand of the first armature.

The problem: My animation in blender looks good in terms of everything functioning the way I intend, I key frame the constraints, and all necessary motions to produce the desired results, however when I bring the animation into Unity, all clips from the blend file besides the reload become deformed, or the reload animation breaks, and everything ends up broken. (I've now redone this twice unfortunately).

Things I've Tried: I have baked the animations to try and preserve the needed key frame data within the constraints due to the fact that Unity does not recognize Blender constraints, and this did not help, deformation still happen to the magazines transforms within Unity. I've tried using no bones and simply animating as an object parented to the weapon, however this produce even more poor results similar to those listed above. I've attempted no baking, layers in Unity with separate animation, and some other minuscule tests and tries.

Feeling pretty lost at this point and feel I am completely missing the mark on the workflow in which I should be taking, however the tutorials and very little documentation that I have found suggests that using "ChildOf" constraints on the armature is the best method for weapon reloads. Any advice is very much appreciated! Thanks.[image]

Comment: Did you Apply (Ctrl A) all rotations and scale to all your objects and rigs? The more usual way is to bake the animation of all deforming bones removing all constraints and exporting the group (mesh and its rig) in the fbx format, with no need of further parenting, as the exact location of all vertices in assured by the armatures.

Comment: I did uniform scaling and rotation with Ctrl A and had the same results but I could definitely try baking again with the removal of the constraints at the end and then export as an .FBX instead for sure, that is a great suggestion, I will try! Thank you! @joshsanfelici